# How in MongoDB find needed object by number with find() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to find an identical objects in my database and everything works fine for me, but for some reason the year (digit) search doesn't work.
I made the year a number but somehow it didn't work with parseInt(). It's very interesting what I'm doing wrong

[image]

My mongoose schema

[image]

How my data base look:

[image]

Comment: Post code, not images of code. Try `year: +req.body.year,` (the `+` will turn text into a number)

Comment: from the payload you get a string, not a number